# Wordpress - get the userID from custom user meta

Tags: php, wordpress, userid, meta-key

I try to get the wordpress `USER ID` from a userMeta key I created during the registration.

The user meta key is 'lh_scuritycode' with meta value `$_GET["key"]`.

`$_GET["key"] = f16dea7e995b14e420ddb96fb7dbd67f`

This is my code:

```
<?php

if ((ctype_alnum($_GET["key"])) && (strlen($_GET["key"]) == 32)) {

    $lh_users = get_users( array(
                    "meta_key" => "lh_scuritycode",
                    "meta_value" => $_GET["key"],
                    "number" => 1,
                    "count_total" => false
                ) );

    foreach ($lh_users as $lh_user) {
        echo '<li>' . $lh_user->id . '</li>';
    }

} else {    
    echo "Der String ".$_GET["key"]." ist fehlerhaft.\n";   
}

?>
```

Now, `$lh_users` is only an array if I `echo` it. When I use the `foreach` it works. How can I do it without that `foreach`?

when I do this "var_dump" the result is:

> array(1) { [0]=> object(WP_User)#126 (7) { ["data"]=>
>   object(stdClass)#2077 (10) { ["ID"]=> string(2) "24" ["user_login"]=>
>   string(7) "Aner" ["user_pass"]=> string(34) "$P$BDpMKv0"
>   ["user_nicename"]=> string(7) "aner" ["user_email"]=> string(18)
>   "infe" ["user_url"]=> string(0) "" ["user_registered"]=>
>   string(19) "2013-0 1:02" ["user_activation_key"]=> string(0)
>   "" ["user_status"]=> string(1) "0" ["display_name"]=> string(7)
>   "Aner" } ["ID"]=> int(24) ["caps"]=> array(1) { ["subscriber"]=>
>   bool(true) } ["cap_key"]=> string(22) "localhero_capabilities"
>   ["roles"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(10) "subscriber" } ["allcaps"]=>
>   array(3) { ["read"]=> bool(true) ["level_0"]=> bool(true)
>   ["subscriber"]=> bool(true) } ["filter"]=> NULL } }

And How do I echo this ARRAY1[id]?

Thanks to GWC

I do it this way:

```
if ((ctype_alnum($_GET["key"])) && (strlen($_GET["key"]) == 32)) {

$lh_users = get_users( array(
"meta_key" => "lh_scuritycode",
"meta_value" => $_GET["key"],
"number" => 1, "fields" => "ID"
) );

$this_user = $lh_users[0];

echo $this_user;
```

Comment: what does `var_dump($lh_users);` look like post in question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If all you want is a list of user IDs:

```
$lh_users = get_users( array(
                "meta_key" => "lh_scuritycode",
                "meta_value" => $_GET["key"],
                "fields" => "ID"
            ) );

echo '<li>' . implode( '</li><li>', $lh_users ) . '</li>';
```

Comment: Hi, the $_GET["key"] will only match 1 userID. So I dont need a list, I just want to store the ID in an other string. for example $the_user.